# Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body in vertx

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x, coroutine

I have the following code that does not get compiled:

```
private suspend fun createRoutes(router: Router, auth: OAuth2Auth): Unit {

    val oauth2 = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(vertx, auth)
    val authz = KeycloakAuthorization.create()


    router.route().handler(LoggerHandler.create())

    router.route("/api/*").handler(oauth2)

    router.route("/api/greet").handler {

      println(RoleBasedAuthorization.create("ad-admins").match(it.user()))
      authz.getAuthorizations(it.user()).await()
    }

  }
```

the compiler complains:

```
Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body
```

Without coroutine, I have to write in callback style:

```
  private fun createRoutes(router: Router, auth: OAuth2Auth): Unit {

    val oauth2 = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(vertx, auth)
    val authz = KeycloakAuthorization.create()


    router.route().handler(LoggerHandler.create())

    router.route("/api/*").handler(oauth2)

     router.route("/api/greet").handler {

      println(RoleBasedAuthorization.create("ad-admins").match(it.user()))

      authz.getAuthorizations(it.user())
        .onSuccess { _ ->

          println(RoleBasedAuthorization.create("ad-admins").match(it.user()))

          val res = it.response()
          res.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")

          // Write to the response and end it
          res.end("I am interests path")

        }
    }
  }
```

However I would like to use coroutine instead callback style.

**Update**

That is the whole code:

```
class MainVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {

  private suspend fun initConfig(): JsonObject {
    val yamlConfigOpts = ConfigStoreOptions()
      .setFormat("yaml")
      .setType("file")
      .setConfig(JsonObject().put("path", "config.yaml"))

    val configRetrieverOpts = ConfigRetrieverOptions()
      .addStore(yamlConfigOpts)

    val configRetriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, configRetrieverOpts)

    return configRetriever.config.await()
  }


  private suspend fun createJwtAuth(): OAuth2Auth =

    KeycloakAuth.discover(
      vertx,
      OAuth2Options()
        .setFlow(OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE)
        .setClientID("svc")
        .setClientSecret("9d782e45-67e7-44b1-9b74-864f45f9a18f")
        .setSite("https://oic.dev.databaker.io/auth/realms/databaker")
    ).await()


  private suspend fun createRoutes(router: Router, auth: OAuth2Auth): Unit {
    

    val oauth2 = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(vertx, auth)
    val authz = KeycloakAuthorization.create()


    router.route().handler(LoggerHandler.create())

    router.route("/api/*").handler(oauth2)

     router.route("/api/greet").handler {

      println(RoleBasedAuthorization.create("ad-admins").match(it.user()))

      authz.getAuthorizations(it.user()).await()
    }

  }


  private suspend fun server(router: Router): HttpServer {
    val server = vertx.createHttpServer()

    return server.requestHandler(router)
      .listen(8080)
      .onSuccess {
        println("HTTP server started on port ${it.actualPort()}")
      }
      .onFailure {
        println("Failed to start the server. Reason ${it.message}")
      }
      .await()
  }


  override suspend fun start() {

    val router = Router.router(vertx)


    createRoutes(router, createJwtAuth())
    server(router)

  }

}
```

The error that I get is on:

```
authz.getAuthorizations(it.user()).await()
```

Comment: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines/kotlin/

Comment: But I do not know, how to do the implementation. Could you please provide an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use coroutine inside the router.route("/api/\*").handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64959205/how-to-use-coroutine-inside-the-router-route-api-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to writing some kind of wrapper in Kotlin, using coroutines is really easy. For starters, take a look at the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html).

The coroutine can be as simple as `GlobalScope.launch { createRoutes(router, auth) }`

Comment: I know that Vert.x provides simple solution for that but unfortunately I do not know how to do the implenmentation.

Comment: `authz.getAuthorizations(it.user())` returns future.

Comment: GlobalScope is something should avoid to be used

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `GlobalScope` in Vert.x code, since it will break the concept of structured concurrency.

To start a coroutine from CoroutineVerticle, you can simply use launch() function:

```kotlin
router.route("/api/greet").handler {
    launch {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

You'll have to mark your function with the `suspend` keyword though.